# Node.js HTTP module

Tags: node.js, httpmodule

Consider the following two codes:

```
require('http').createServer()
.on('request', (req, res) => { ... })
.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running") );
```

and

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => { ... });
server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running") );
```

I have the following questions:

1. Are there benefits in simply running the first code with chaining functions without assigning to constant or is it better to assign the required **HTTP module** to `const http`, repectively the **Server object** to `const server`? Are the implications regarding how the program will run?
2. Is it better to put the `(req, res) => { ... }` request handler inside the `on` event handler function for ***REQUEST event*** or inside the `CreateServer` function?

Comment: It's generally just a matter of taste

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for your answer! I don't see a big difference in declaring two constants, but I am not sure how Node.js is handeling things here. From my tests I see that either way, `require('http')` is run just once and the program consumes just the request events by means of `.listen()`